# Getting WebPack multi vendor error - Cannot resolve module 'babel-runtime'

Tags: webpack, babeljs, rxjs5

I've just started using the https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic library and its going well except for an issue that I haven't been able to resolve.  I'm not sure what's causing it, but it started when I installed this library and also the required RXJs library (5.0.0-beta.12), and updated WebPack (1.13.2) and Babel (core 6.14) to handle the ES2016 features.

The babel-runtime is in dependencies, babel-plugin-transform-runtime is in devDependencies. I've checked multiple times.  I dont see any index.js file though, but I'm not sure there is on

I've tried clearing the NPM cache, removing and reinstalling node_modules, changing parameters on the webpack CommonsChunkPlugin, .bablerc, etc for 2 days and the exception is still thrown in the browser.  Even odder, the application seems to be working, but I cant have this browser exception.

I'd love to post the actual output from WebPack, but after 20+ tries, SO is still complaining that my post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.  So here it is as a Gist:

https://gist.github.com/MrRoyce/4e9b0ca0747541893848b19206cea2f8

Here is .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }],
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your Webpack config.

Comment: I had the same problem.  In my particular case it was because I was telling webpack to split out all of the dependencies listed in package.json into a separate chunk; this caused it to try to load `babel-runtime` directly which fails because it doesn't have an entry.